# How to end a script after an "if" statement

Tags: c#

I want to use an if statement where on one outcome it continues the script and on the other it ends it entirely. I know break exists but you cannot use it in this situation but I will happily be corrected on this. Example code is below if anyone can help that would be great.

```
Console.WriteLine("Do you want to continue Y/N?");
String stringName = Console.ReadLine();
string stringNameUC = stringName.ToUpper();

if (stringNameUC == "Y")
{
Console.WriteLine("...");
//This is where I want the script to continue
}
else
{
Console.WriteLine("...");
//This is where I want the script to end
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards
Curtis

Comment: Just call `return;` ?

Comment: Where is this code? What type of project / application? Makes a big difference.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you just add an `return;`?

```
Console.WriteLine("Do you want to continue Y/N?");
String stringName = Console.ReadLine();
string stringNameUC = stringName.ToUpper();

if (stringNameUC != "Y")
{
   Console.WriteLine("...");
   return;
}
// Continue with your logic here
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. When I add return in any code under the if block does not run which is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a "return" will continue your code. Depending on what your next step is you can just add the code you want to run inside the {} of the if statement.  Assuming you want to do more than just run some simple code you can call another method from your if "true" to move on in the code.

Your else will have a return.  This will end the if statement and continue on to your next section of code as long as there is a next.  :)

```
if (stringNameUC == "Y")
{
    Console.WriteLine("...");
    //Assuming simple code add it here OR
    //callSomeClass.Method();
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("...");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Yes this is partly what I've been doing using the return; and just carrying on the script within the if statement and that all works. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

Well, that depends on where this codeblock is located and how you call it.

- If this is all of your code, the script will end either way, because there is no more code to execute.
- If this codeblock is part of a function, calling `return;` will exit the function.
- If this is part of of the `Main` function you can also call `Environment.Exit(1)` which will end the executing process.

Comment: I've just had a look at this, I'm not sure if I'm going wrong somewhere I'm fairly new to C# but when I try use System.Exit it throws up the error "'Console' does not contain a definition for 'Exit'".

Comment: Ah sorry, it's `Environment.Exit(1)`. Mixed that up with java ...